# Simple word count in haskell

Tags: haskell

This is my FIRST haskell program! "wordCount" takes in a list of words and returns a tuple with with each case-insensitive word paired with its usage count. Any suggestions for improvement on either code readability or performance?

```
import List;
import Char;
uniqueCountIn ns xs = map (\x -> length (filter (==x) xs)) ns
nubl (xs) = nub (map (map toLower) xs) -- to lowercase
wordCount ws =  zip ns (uniqueCountIn ns ws)
   where ns = nubl ws
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Congrats on your first program!

For cleanliness: lose the semicolons. Use the new hierarchical module names instead (`Data.List`, `Data.Char`).  Add type signatures.  As you get more comfortable with function composition, eta contract your function definitions (remove rightmost arguments). e.g.

```
nubl :: [String] -> [String]
nubl = nub . map (map toLower)
```

If you want to be really rigorous, use explicit import lists:

```
import Data.List (nub) 
import Data.Char (toLower)
```

For performance: use a [`Data.Map`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html) to store the associations instead of `nub` and `filter`.  In particular, see [`fromListWith`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html#v%3AfromListWith) and [`toList`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html#v%3AtoList).  Using those functions you can simplify your implementation and improve performance at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, tonight I'll fix it up with those suggestions. You earned that karma :)

Answer (score 18):

One of the ways to improve readibility is to try to get used to the standard functions. [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is one of the tools that sets Haskell apart from the rest of the world ;)

```
import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.List (sort, group)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))

wordCount :: String -> [(String, Int)]
wordCount = map (head &&& length) . group . sort . words . map toLower
```

**EDIT**: Explanation: So you think of it as a chain of mappings:

- `(map toLower) :: String -> String` lowercases the entire text, for the purpose of case
  insensitivity
- `words :: String -> [String]` splits a piece of text into words
- `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` sorts
- `group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]` gathers identicial elements in a list, for example, `group
  [1,1,2,3,3]` -> `[[1,1],[2],[3,3]]`
- `&&& :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (a -> (b, c))` applies two functions on the same piece of data, then returns
  the tuple of results. For example: `(head &&& length) ["word","word","word"]` -> `("word", 3)` (actually `&&&` is a little more general, but the simplified explanation works for this example)

**EDIT**: Or actually, look for the "multiset" package on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html).

Comment: abstract functional implementation not suitable for a beginner (eg. `&&&`), also with no explanation. -1

Comment: OK, let me add the explanation T_T

Comment: much better.  I like the order of the chain and that you included type signatures so we can see how the data transforms on its way through the chain.

Comment: I'm still very new and could follow this logic (after reading the explanation). I think this reads a LOT better than my code, lol.

Answer (score 6):

It is always good to ask more experienced developers for feedback. Nevertheless you could use [hlint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/) to get feedback on some small scale issues. It'll tell you about hierarchical imports, unncessary parenthesis, alternative higher-order functions, etc.

Regarding the function, `nub1`. If you don't follow luqui's advice to remove the parameter altogether yet, I would at least remove the parenthesis around `xs` on the right side of the equation.